# LaTeX to PDF to PDFCrop to PNG by ImageMagick -- How to get PNG dimensions to not exceed 600 in width

Tags: pdf, png, pdfcrop

I create PNGs from LaTeX files by first cropping the content from the PDF output using PDFCrop and then converting to PNG using ImageMagick.  I always use the same settings but the width of the PNG files varies for some reason.  I cannot have a PNG width exceeding 600 (height does not matter).

The ImageMagick PNG parameters are set at 600 density and scaled to 17%, a combination I find perfect.  The PNGs contain text and the 600 density 17% scaling combination provides perfect clarity/readability for my application.  But like I said some of the PNG outputs end up with a width just over 600.  My PNG application shrinks those, so I lose the clarity/readability of the text in the PNG.

**LaTeX file example 1:**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
\nofiles
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[papersize={500px,110px},margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}
\sansmath

\noindent It is estimated that $t$ years from now, the population of a certain suburban community will be $\displaystyle p(t)=40-\frac{5}{7 t+3}$ thousand people. At what rate will the population be growing 5 years from now?

\end{document}
```

**LaTeX file example 2:**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
\nofiles
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[papersize={500px,110px},margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}
\sansmath

\noindent Find $\displaystyle \frac{d y}{d x}$ at $x = -1$ if $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{3 u-1}$ and $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{x+2}$.

\end{document}
```

**Batch file for PDFCrop and ImageMagick:**

```
for %%f in (*.tex) do (

    pdflatex %%~nf.tex

    pdfcrop %%~nf.pdf %%~nf.pdf

    magick convert -alpha off -density 600 %%~nf.pdf -scale 17%% %%~nf.png
)
```

The PNG output from Example 1 is 629 x 67. This is over 600 in width so this is bad.

The PNG output from Example 2 is 335 x 37. This is under 600 in width so this is good.

I need to process more than 100 of these LaTeX files to PNG.  Is there a setting or parameter change that will do the trick while preserving the 600 density 17% scaling combination?  Could the change be made in the LaTeX file?

Comment: I often convert at `cmd` with `magick -density 960 x.pdf x.png` (never try for several files at a time)

Comment: Add `-resize 600x^>` after `-scale 17%%`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008440/12652399

Comment: @DavidPurton This has the same effect.  It shrinks the size of the images greater than 600 wide losing the clarity/readability of the 600/17 combination.

Comment: I deleted the LaTeX line ```\usepackage[papersize={500px,110px},margin=1cm]{geometry}``` and that did it.  I thought controlling the paper size this way would work but it did not.